# ChartJs - displaying data dynamically from back-end

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I have been struggling with this one for days now, really need some help. I need to apply gradient colors and some custom styling to our ChartJs bar chart, that contains call reporting data which comes from the back-end server. I found a way how to apply the styles and gradients, but can't figure out how to configure datasets to display correct data from the server, instead of some random numbers (eg. 10,20,30), like I tried for gradientGreen below. Any ideas?

//main html

```
<div class="row mb-4 mt-4">
    <div class="col-9">
        <h4 class="text-center">Call Distribution</h4>
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("HourlyCallTotals", new { from = Model.From, to = Model.To, customer = Model.customer, site = Model.site })
</div>
```

//component html

```
@model CallReporter.ViewModels.BasicFilter
<div id="hourlyChart">
</div>
<script>
    var HourlyCallData = @Html.RenderAction("HourlyTotals", "Calls", "", new { from = Model.from.ToString("s"), to = Model.to.ToString("s"), customer = Model.customer, site = Model.site })
</script>
```

//relevant part of JS function for Chart

```
function hoursChartAjax() {
    var hourlyChart = $('#hourlyChart').html('<canvas width="400" height="300"></canvas>').find('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    // set gradients for bars
    let gradientGreen = hourlyChart.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    gradientGreen.addColorStop(0, '#66d8b0');
    gradientGreen.addColorStop(1, '#1299ce');

    let gradientBlue = hourlyChart.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    gradientBlue.addColorStop(0, '#1299ce');
    gradientBlue.addColorStop(1, '#2544b7');

    if (hourlyChart !== undefined) {
        $.get(base + "Calls/HourlyTotals", { from: from.format(), to: to.format(), customer: currentCustomer.id, site: currentSite }, function (data) {
            // set the default fonts for the chart
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Nunito';
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#787878';
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;

            var chart = new Chart(hourlyChart, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['6AM', '9AM', '12AM', '3PM', '6PM', '9PM', '12PM'],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Total outgoing calls',
                            backgroundColor: gradientBlue,
                            data: HourlyCallData
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Total incoming calls',
                            backgroundColor: gradientGreen,
                            data: [10, 20, 30]
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

//relevant part of back-end code that returns call data as Json

```
 totalsContainer.Totals = allCallsHourly.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();

             return Json(new
            {
                labels = totalsContainer.Totals.Select(x => x.Date.ToString("hh tt")),
                 datasets = new List<object>() {
                    new { label = "Total Outgoing Calls", backgroundColor = "#1299CE", data = totalsContainer.Totals.Select(x => x.TotalOutgoingCalls) },                    
                    new { label = "Total Incoming Calls", backgroundColor = "#00B050", data = totalsContainer.Totals.Select(x => x.TotalIncomingCalls) } }
            });
```

Attached img with console log and error, after trying solution below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the data comes formatted in the right way, you can just write this:

```
var chart = new Chart(hourlyChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data: data
}
```

If not you could do it like so:

```
var chart = new Chart(hourlyChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: data.labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: data.datasets[0].label,
                backgroundColor: gradientBlue,
                data: data.datasets[0].data
            },
            {
                label: data.datasets[1].label,
                backgroundColor: gradientGreen,
                data: data.datasets[1].data
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried both of your solutions, they don't seem to work and chart doesn't get rendered at all. When I try 2nd solution, it gives an error in console: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse".......which suggests I shouldn't be parsing that data at all?

Comment: @ZoranK no that means that your data you get from your backend is invalid. Try to log it and append the output to the question please.

Comment: I have console logged the data before it tries to parse it, can you please see the image in OP and offer some insight?

Comment: What happens when you write `console.log(data.datasets[0]); console.log(data.datasets[0].label)` before the `Chart.defaults.global ....` stuff? @ZoranK.

Comment: It loggs "Total Outgoing Calls" dataset and label as it is supposed to, so the actual data coming back seems ok to me. Is there anything else I could use on JSON data instead of parsing to use it in my javascript? @MauriceNino

Comment: Then just write `data: data` instead of of `data: JSON.parse(data)`. @ZoranK.

Comment: Awesome that worked, thx Maurice for helping out. Still struggling with how to properly connect both front-end and back-end. If you want to amend your initial answer, I have accepted it as a solution. Have a great day

Comment: Glad I could help. If you struggle with it and just want to develop a quick product, I would suggest you using products like Firebase or AWS or similar. They aim to make it as easy as possible to create your own backend without having to manage it. PS: I edited my answer, you can accept it now.

Comment: No worries, I have used firebase and it's so easy and more approachable, but this is an old project at my company with some in-house solutions which makes things harder and my senior dev doesn't really have time for me it seems.